# Python only prints the last list in a 2d list

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2D array of vocabulary words that I scraped from a website. Now what I am trying to do is, print each list of the 2D array in it's own `.txt` file but, when it writes it, it only writes the last list in the 2D array. This is my first time trying to write a 2D array to a `.txt` file. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I'm trying to write 20 of the lists in the 2d list to 20 different .txt files.

This is what I am using to write the `.txt` file with the 2D array

So far I've tried using 'a' instead of 'w' but that writes the whole 2d list to the .txt file (IE it makes 20 .txt files with all of the contents of the 2d list)

```
for words in souparray:
    with open(path + sublink + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as txtf:
        str1 = ''.join(words)
        txtf.write(str1)
        str1 = ""
```

Comment: The last list in the 2d array gets written in all files?

Comment: @Nurzhan Yea, it only writes the last list in the 2d list. so if there is[ [x,y,z] , [a,b,c]] it will only write a b c

Comment: How many files?

Comment: @Nurzhan I have 20 URL that have different vocab words so, it's a jagged 2d list. there are 20 text files that i'm trying to make

Comment: Are you changing `path` and `sublink` anywhere?

Comment: @Prajwal yes I am, when i grab the URLs. I am grabbing the last number of  it. so when it writes the txt files it goes 1,2,3 ect but it only has the last list in the txt files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you write everything to the same file. You need to change the name files you write to:

```
for words in souparray:
    with open(path + sublink + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as txtf:
        str1 = ''.join(words)
        txtf.write(str1)
        str1 = ""
```

The `sublink` should change with each iteration. Or you need to add some counter if the sublink part does not change.

For instance:

```
...
count = 0

for words in souparray:
    with open(path + sublink + count + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as txtf:
        str1 = ''.join(words)
        txtf.write(str1)
        str1 = ""
    count+=1
    txtf.close()
```

Comment: Clearly he wants to write it to one file, he is just using the wrong mode.

Comment: @Natecat Read the comments. He clearly stated that he needs separate files. Please, read more attentively before downvoting!

Comment: Please, read more attentively before blindly scolding me. He is changing the path sublink for each file, but the code doesn't include that, therefore the different text files are created by looping this entire block. Notice how he said text files, plural, in his last comment?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to the file, the writing mode overrides the content of the file and deletes what was previously in the file.

You want to append to the file so you should use the append method when you open the file. This will work,

```
for words in souparray:
    with open(path + sublink + '.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as txtf:
        str1 = ''.join(words)
        txtf.write(str1)
        str1 = ""
```

Comment: Using 'a' writes the whole 2d array to the txt file. I'm trying to get 20 different txt files with each list printed into one

Comment: Do you have a list of sub links?

Comment: yes(?) I have a list of all the urls that I am using.

Comment: Did Nurzhan's answer work for you?

Comment: No it didn't I'm already changing the name of each txt file with the sublink

Comment: Well I need some more information then, what is this sublink in your code snippet? Is it a list and you are iterating over it and it's value is changing? If you are iterating over it where are you iterating over it?

Comment: I'm sorry. I will clarify more at the end on the url's there is a 1-20. I am grabing that and saving it to an array sublink = link[72:-1]

Comment: This gives me [this](http://imgur.com/a/0045F) but, when i open it, it is the last list of the 2d array in every text life. like [this](http://imgur.com/a/3XriB)

Comment: Well then it looks like you are doing it the wrong way. You are iterating over the whole **souparray**, and then you are just pushing out every element in the same file. Because **sublink** is a constant inside the loop while you do the computation. You need to change the value of sublink inside the loop. And the thing will work.

Comment: Getting somewhere now. Only thing is it keeps making txt files nonstop.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it fixed if i commented out the sublink for loop. I'm not sure why but if i leave it there it keeps making text files.